# Meteor - unmount existing mongo collection

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-collections

We are creating Meteor-based Mongo database manager and we need the ability to "unmount" (remove from system) all collections when we switch databases.

Example:

- I'm managing database called dbA. We have all collections for that database created using Mongo.Collection() on server and on client side.
- I want to switch database to dbB. I need to unmount all Collections of dbA and mount those of dbB. Reason: dbB could have a collection of the same name as dbA (and usually does)

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: afaik this would require restarting the Meteor server and having it point at the other mongodb.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to accomplish this by publishing the necessary data from the new database.

Here's a discussion from a similar question on the Meteor Forums (note the proposed solution at the end):
https://forums.meteor.com/t/switch-database-while-meteor-is-running/4361/5

Answer (score -1):

hi i think you can do with

`db.copyDatabase()`

1. run the shell command in the backend from meteor server and execute the copy database command. and after the database is copied you can remove the previous collection.
   more detail about copyDatabase() is here
   https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.copyDatabase/

Comment: i think the switching of db from the meteor app? i mean the requirement.